# How do I set an environment variable in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

In linux I would go:

```
setenv -p MYVAR "somevalue"
```

But this doesn't seem to work in cygwin.

Comment: Please elaborate: what shell are you using?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives me back /bin/sh - google tells me this is the Bourne shell.

Comment: Ok - I got it - for Bourne shell it's VAR=value.

Comment: setenv works in C shell

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By default Cygwin is running the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) or [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), so the command to set a variable is different. This is the code you need:

```
export MYVAR="somevalue"
```

The `export` part lets the shell know that it is an environment variable instead of a local variable.

If you type `ls -a` in your home directory, you should see some or all of the following files:

```
.bashrc
.bash_profile
.profile
```

`.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, and `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells. To most simply ensure that your environment variable is always set, open up `.bash_profile` and add the text:

```
export MYVAR="somevalue"
```

Your shell with then execute `.bash_profile` every time it starts up, and it will run this command. You will then have the `MYVAR` variable accessible all of the time. If you didn't `export` the variable, it would only be accessible within your `.bash_profile` file.

You can check that this variable is defined by printing its value to your shell:

```
echo $MYVAR
```

You can delete (unset) the variable with:

```
unset $MYVAR
```

## Brief words on shell config files

As an aside, regarding `.bashrc` vs `.bash_profile` vs. `.profile`, see these answers:

- [difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc)
- [difference between `.profile` and `.bash_profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile)

For simplicity of configuration, I recommend sourcing your `.bashrc` file from `.bash_profile`. Add this to `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ${HOME}/.bashrc ]; then
   source ${HOME}/.bashrc
fi
```

This will load `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`.

If you do this, you can instead put the following line in `.bashrc`, if you wish:

```
export MYVAR="somevalue"
```

Comment: will MYVAR still be there next time I boot up cygwin?

Comment: @BeeBand I just updated my answer. If you type in the command only in your shell, you will have it until you exit your shell. If you put it in a configuration file, you will have it every time you use the shell. If you modify your configuration file and don't restart your shell, you can type `~/.bashrc` to execute the configuration file without restarting.

Comment: @dbmikus - you can also add that, you can access the value of the enviroment variable like this - `$MYVAR`. To see the value of the variable, type `echo $MYVAR`.

Comment: To delete an env variable, use the unset command. `unset $MYVAR`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @Steam. I added those in. I've tried to keep the information ordered from most relevant to least relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to set up environment variables in cygwin is to create a bash profile and execute that profile everytime you login and run the shell.

In my .bash_profile file , this is the setting I have

```
JAVA_HOME = C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Once you run bash, check out echo $JAVA_HOME and you should see the path as output.