# Foundation 5 SCSS installation and Prepros

Tags: zurb-foundation, prepros

I installed ruby, Git and Node.js. Then instruction says "Bash", what exactly is Bash? I am using windows and I am newbie for thoese 3 apps they listed.

Is it windows default cmd.exe? ruby.exe or git?

If I manage it to work and created foundation project folder. How to make the foundation5 work with Prepros?

Comment: You can use PowerShell on Windows. Very powerful ! You just need to install ruby, compass, node, git and npm. After that, use : `foundation new your_project`

Answer (score 0):

Bash is a Unix Shell, which basically allows you to type commands on your computer to execute tasks.

When you install Git on Windows, you also get a version of Git Bash, which you can use for Git commands.

Your best bet is to use something like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which replicates unix functionality on a Windows machine. Once you have installed Cygwin, you may need to set up your PATH environment variable so that when you execute `git` or `ruby` commands, they know where to look.

There is some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444502/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-in-cygwin) on setting up environment variables.